# What is the proper reading order for the Grimm Fairy Tales?

Tags: suggested-order, fairy-tales, grimm-fairy-tales

I have recently gotten into the Zenoscope Grimm Fairy Tales. I have read 1-12 of the trade paper backs, the Dream Eater saga, and Myths and Legends.

However, as I'm reading, I'm noticing the order isn't exactly correct. Can someone please post the proper order to read the series as of the newest issue?

Comment: Very extensively discussed [here](http://cmro.travis-starnes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=3578)